# My data is not sended to database through PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form on a website. I need to save my information to database. I made a database in localhost but when I click on submit it displays the whole code of register.php in the same page and no data saved in database,i have placed all the files in htdocs. I have form in index.html and register.php file is seperate. Here the php file:

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    if(!$link){
        die('could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'connected successfully';
    mysql_select_db(learnqurandb);

        $name = $_post['fullname'];
        $email = $_post['email'];
        $mobile = $_post['mobile'];
        $country = $_post['country'];
        $course = $_post['course'];
        $skype_id = $_post['skype'];

     if($name == ""){
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your name')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if($email == ""){
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your E-mail')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if($mobile == ""){
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your Mobile Numbet')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if($country == ""){
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your country name')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if($course == ""){
        echo "<script>alert('please select your desire course')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if($skype_id == ""){
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your Skype ID')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    $check_skype_id = "select * from learnquran where skype = '$skype_id";
    $count = mysql_query('$check_skype_id');

    if(mysql_num_rows ($count) > 0){

        echo"<script>alert('Skype_id $skype_id is already exists, please try another one.')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO registration (fullname,email,mobile,country,course,skype) values('$name','$email','$mobile','$country','$course','$skype_id')";

    if(mysql_query ($query)){

        echo "<script>alert('Registration Successfull')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

my html form is this

```
<div id="form_div">
        <h2>Quick Registration</h2>
        <form name="Form1" method="post" action="register.php" />
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fname" /><br><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="user_email" /><br><br>
        <label for="mobile">Mobile:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="user_mobile" /><br><br>
        <label for="country">Country:</label>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="user_country" /><br><br>
        <label for="skype">Skype ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="skype" id="skype_id" /><br><br>
        <label for="course">Course:</label>
        <select name="course" id="desired_course" ><br><br>
        <option value="Select course..." selected>Select course</option><br>
        <option value="Quran Reading">Quran Reading</option>
        <option value="Memorizing the Holy Quran">Memorizing Holy      Quran</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="button1" value=""/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: `"it display the whole code of register.php in the same page"` - If you're seeing PHP code in your browser then PHP isn't executing at all on your server.  Either PHP isn't installed or isn't configured correctly.

Comment: `mysql_query('$check_skype_id')` wont work, use `"` instead of `'` , bettter leave them complety

Comment: your `$check_skype_id` query need a closeing `'` at the end

Comment: Please use at Tool like `netbeans` to produce your code

Comment: You should fix the grammar in your next question and make sure that your code doesn't contain a load of errors

Comment: as long as you write and not use your code place `error_report(E_ALL);` at the first (e.g. second) line of the php file

Comment: thanks to all i try my best to do as you guys suggest me and know when i click on submit button after adding information it show this error on browser Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'skype_id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\register.php on line 42

Comment: @joum suggest me something
$check_skype_id = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE skype_id = '$skype_id'";
  $count = mysql_query("$check_skype_id");
 
  if(mysql_num_rows ($count) > 0){

   echo "<script>alert("skype_id, $skype_id is already exists please try another one")</script>";
   exit();
  }
line 42 is last line that is echo statment

Answer (score 0):

You should be using PDO instead of mysql_connect as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Please view this tutorial on how to use PDO. Here's more information about it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtCdk459NFg&list=PLfdtiltiRHWHkDwEoZ29Q9FKtWVjA46HC

As for your code just displaying on your screen, make sure that your server has php enabled.